# Can I make a Powerpoint slide larger, with scrolling (to fit more elements)?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm making a wireframe for a website and I'm considering using Powerpoint.  But I have a lot of fields to fit on some of the site's pages--maybe 50 or 60, so it's definitely more than can fit on a regular slide.  Is there a way to "stretch out" a slide so that I can put more elements on it, and then scroll to reach them while I'm viewing the slide show, the same way I would stretch out an Access form if I needed to fit a lot of content?

Comment: Why don't you use something built to do wireframes like https://gomockingbird.com/
If you want something for the desktop, inkscape is nice to do wireframes too: http://inkscape.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Resizing the presentation:
>
> 1. In the main ribbon, select the “Design” tab.
> 2. Click on the “Page Setup” icon.
> 3. You can select from predefined formats in the first dropdown menu or
>      specify the “Width” and “Height” in the boxes below.
> 4. In the right side of the dialog box you can customize the
>      orientation of the presentation. Click on the “OK” button.

However, you really shouldn't be using Powerpoint to create a website wireframe. *PowerPoint presentations are designed to fill a computer monitor screen*. They're not meant to be larger than the screen.

There are many better tools for this including: InDesign, Illustrator, and Inkscape. You can even design one online for free with [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/).

Ref: 
http://www.pcrx.com/resource_center/how-do-change-the-slide-size-in-powerpoint.html#ixzz1wwZVvIo5

Comment: Mockingbird works for me.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Powerpoint is the poor man's Visio :) Being about to expand the canvas beyond the dimensions of a screen is vital to that usage.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround to create a scrolling effect is to use the "Draw line" option on the "Custom" menu using the "Motion" feature on the "Animations" tab. A straight vertical line in an upwards direction in the exact middle of the frame will have the effect of scrolling. You can slow it right down to 25 or 30 seconds or so, to give people time to read it.